# How to hide some issue link types in the Issue Link pop up window for Jira 5.1.8 using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jira

I wanted to hide some issue link outward & inwards strings of Link type from the Link Issues Popup Window using java script.

I have tried using java script but I am not getting the popup screen from the java script.

Please see the screenshot below :

[image: Hide Issue Link types]

Can anyone tell me how can I get this popup screen in the java script?
Is there any other method to hide this?

Thanks & Regards,

Renuka.

Comment: answer updated , have a look :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To hide the clone issue link every page:**

edit the file `system-webresources-plugin.xml` (should be at /atlassian-jira/WEB-INF/classes/), and add to `<web-resource key="jira-fields">` this code:

```
    <resource type="download" name="myScript.js" location="/includes/jira/field/script.js">
        <param name="source" value="webContextStatic"/>
    </resource>
```

than, on `/includes/jira/field/myScript.js` write this:

```
AJS.$(document).ready(function() {
    if (AJS.$("#link-type option[value*='clon']").size() > 0) {
        // will work even when right clicking on More 
        // Actions->Link & open it into a new window
        AJS.$("#link-type option[value*='clon']").remove()
    } else if (AJS.$("#link-issue").size() > 0) {
        // will work in case the link menu showing via popup
        AJS.$("#link-issue").click(function(){
            // wait for the popup to show, and remove the clone options
            setTimeout(function (){
                AJS.$("#link-type option[value*='clon']").remove();
             }, 300);
        });
    }
});
```

restart Jira and it that it!

The script attaches a function to the link-menu opening, than gives the menu 0.3 seconds to load, and removes the unwanted items. If it doesn't work well for you, try to raise the timeout from 300 to 500-1000.

On jira 4, run instead:

```
    AJS.$("#issue-link-link-type option[value*='clon']").remove();
```

Comment: Hi Kuf,    Thanks for replying. I tried your script but still no luck!! :(  I am putting this script in Announcement Baner is there any other way to put this script.Thanks!!!

Comment: no its not working on browser console also. it is not getting the pop up window of the issue linking.

Comment: Error: Permission denied to access property 'toString'
I am getting above error on console log

Comment: Hi Kuf, I have tried your above script in the browser console. I am getting following error : SyntaxError: missing } in XML expression
data:

Comment: I thought that 5.x used code like 

<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
 
    JIRA.bind(JIRA.Events.NEW_CONTENT_ADDED, function (e, context) {

Comment: Hi Kuf, This script is not working when I right click on More Actions->Link & open it into a new window.  How can I achieve that???

Comment: Try using setInterval() instead of setTimeout() , this will solve the open in new window issue . let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @Mizan, the problem was that when writing this on `Announcement Banner` it won't work when  right clicking on More Actions->Link & open it into a new window. That's why i've updated my answer. I can't see why to use 'setInterval' instead of `setTimeout` since we want to run this script only once.

Comment: Hi Mizan, setInterval is working when I click on Web Link & then I click on Jira Issue on the popup for Link.

Comment: Hi Kuf, I do not want it to run once it should run if I click on some other link then again click on Jira issue the js should work. setInterval is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

The previous solution has an issue:
It will only work when *clicking* the "Link Issue"-Menu-Item.
When I use the Point (.)-Shortcut-Menu, it won't remove the issue types.

I have established the following solution:

JS-Binding-Part:

```
AJS.$(document).ready(function() {
JIRA.bind(JIRA.Events.NEW_CONTENT_ADDED, function(e, context, reason) {
     hideIssueLinkTypes();
  });
});
```

JS-Backing-Function:

```
function hideIssueLinkTypes() {
var apiURL = "/rest/scriptrunner/latest/custom/getHiddenLinkTypes"

  $.getJSON( apiURL, {
  }).done(function( objectData ) {
      $.each( objectData, function( i, item ) {
        var issueLinkType = item.issueLinkType[0];
        AJS.$("#link-type option[value='"+issueLinkType.inwardDescription+"']").remove();
        AJS.$("#link-type option[value='"+issueLinkType.outwardDescription+"']").remove();
      });
    });
}
```

Scriptrunner-REST-Endpoint:

```
import com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.rest.common.CustomEndpointDelegate
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.transform.BaseScript
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.link.DefaultIssueLinkTypeManager
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.link.IssueLinkTypeManager
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.link.IssueLinkType
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.config.properties.ApplicationProperties

import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response


@BaseScript CustomEndpointDelegate delegate

String HIDDEN_IDENT="[hidden]"

getHiddenLinkTypes(httpMethod: "GET") { MultivaluedMap queryParams, String body ->   

    def appProperties = ((ApplicationProperties) ComponentAccessor.getComponentOfType(ApplicationProperties.class));
    def appClonersLinkTypeName = appProperties.getDefaultBackedText("jira.clone.linktype.name");

    def jsBuilder=new JsonBuilder();
    def issueLinkTypes = ((IssueLinkTypeManager) ComponentAccessor.getComponentOfType(IssueLinkTypeManager.class)).getIssueLinkTypes();

    jsBuilder issueLinkTypes.findAll({it.getName().contains(HIDDEN_IDENT) || it.getName()==appClonersLinkTypeName }),
    { IssueLinkType linkType ->
        issueLinkType linkType.getId(),
        name: linkType.getName(),
        inwardDescription: linkType.getInward(),
        outwardDescription: linkType.getOutward()
    }

    return Response.ok(jsBuilder.toString()).build();
}
```

What you can do then ist just annotate and Link-Type with putting [hidden] in the link name and it will disappear for all users (It can still be programmatically added though or created by cloning).

If you don't have Scriptrunner or don't need the dynamic nature of the implementation, you can still hard-code the values as Kuf described in the answer above in hideIssueTypes() like this:

```
AJS.$("#issue-link-link-type option[value*='clon']").remove();
```